# Python Gekko Parameter Estimation: too long computational time because of "Dynamic Init C"

Tags: python, parameters, prediction, gekko, estimation

I have coded a parameter estimation of a 5-state Resistor-Capacitor (RC) model of a large building through Python GEKKO using 5 differential equations in MHE mode (IMODE 5).
The code works fine but the problem is that the computation time becomes too high when the dataset is more than 1 week with 5 mins timesteps (34 parameters to estimate). More than 70% of the time is spent in "Dynamic Init. C" rather than in the solver itself (IPOPT) so I was wondering if someone knows what that "Dynamic Init. C" really means and how I could possibly speed up my model.

The model code is the following:

```python
def train (starting_datetime,finishing_datetime,i,i_max):
    # Import or generate data
    dates = pd.date_range(starting_datetime, finishing_datetime,freq=interp_timestep ,tz="US/Eastern")
    df, location, solar_position, Q_solar_df = weather_data (starting_datetime, finishing_datetime)
    U_train = Power_delivered[starting_datetime:finishing_datetime].values
    X_train = Temp[starting_datetime:finishing_datetime].values
    W_cols = ["T_ext", "Tground_WS", "Tground_NE", "Tground_G", 
          "Q_sol_WS", "Q_sol_NE", "Q_sol_WS_eta", "Q_sol_NE_eta", 
          "Q_int_WS", "Q_int_NE", "Q_int_G", "Q_int_WS_eta", "Q_int_NE_eta", "wind_sq"]  # exogenous_columns
    W_train = df[W_cols].values#.iloc[:-1].values
    time_array = np.arange(0,len(dates)*timestep,timestep)

    # Create GEKKO Model
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    m.time = time_array
    
    # use previous solution as initial values after 5 iterations, before physics based values
    if i > 5:
        Uext_WS_initial = params[i-3]["Uext_WS"]
        Uext_NE_initial = params[i-3]["Uext_NE"]
        Uext_G_initial = params[i-3]["Uext_G"]
        Uext_WS_eta_initial = params[i-3]["Uext_WS_eta"]
        Uext_NE_eta_initial = params[i-3]["Uext_NE_eta"]
        Ug_WS_initial = params[i-3]["Ug_WS"]
        Ug_NE_initial = params[i-3]["Ug_NE"]
        Ug_G_initial = params[i-3]["Ug_G"]
        C_WS_initial = params[i-3]["C_WS"]
        C_NE_initial = params[i-3]["C_NE"]
        C_G_initial = params[i-3]["C_G"]
        C_WS_eta_initial = params[i-3]["C_WS_eta"]
        C_NE_eta_initial = params[i-3]["C_NE_eta"]
        U_WS_initial = params[i-3]["U_WS"]
        U_NE_initial = params[i-3]["U_NE"]
        U_rdc_initial = params[i-3]["U_rdc"]
        U_eta_initial = params[i-3]["U_eta"]
        U_rdc_gym_initial = params[i-3]["U_rdc_gym"]
        U_eta_gym_initial = params[i-3]["U_eta_gym"]
        sigma_WS_initial = params[i-3]["sigma_WS"]
        sigma_NE_initial = params[i-3]["sigma_NE"]
        sigma_G_initial = params[i-3]["sigma_G"]
        sigma_WS_eta_initial = params[i-3]["sigma_WS_eta"]
        sigma_NE_eta_initial = params[i-3]["sigma_NE_eta"]
        lambda_WS_initial = params[i-3]["lambda_WS"]
        lambda_NE_initial = params[i-3]["lambda_NE"]
        lambda_G_initial = params[i-3]["lambda_G"]
        lambda_WS_eta_initial = params[i-3]["lambda_WS_eta"]
        lambda_NE_eta_initial = params[i-3]["lambda_NE_eta"]
        alpha_WS_initial = params[i-3]["alpha_WS"]
        alpha_NE_initial = params[i-3]["alpha_NE"]
        alpha_G_initial = params[i-3]["alpha_G"]
        alpha_WS_eta_initial = params[i-3]["alpha_WS_eta"]
        alpha_NE_eta_initial = params[i-3]["alpha_NE_eta"]
    else:
        Uext_WS_initial = Uext_WS_physics
        Uext_NE_initial = Uext_NE_physics
        Uext_G_initial = Uext_G_physics
        Uext_WS_eta_initial = Uext_WS_eta_physics
        Uext_NE_eta_initial = Uext_NE_eta_physics
        Ug_WS_initial = Ug_WS_physics
        Ug_NE_initial = Ug_NE_physics
        Ug_G_initial = Ug_G_physics
        C_WS_initial = C_WS_physics
        C_NE_initial = C_NE_physics
        C_G_initial = C_G_physics
        C_WS_eta_initial = C_WS_eta_physics
        C_NE_eta_initial = C_NE_eta_physics
        U_WS_initial = U_WS_physics
        U_NE_initial = U_NE_physics
        U_rdc_initial = U_rdc_physics
        U_eta_initial = U_eta_physics
        U_rdc_gym_initial = U_rdc_gym_physics
        U_eta_gym_initial = U_eta_gym_physics
        sigma_WS_initial = 1
        sigma_NE_initial = 1
        sigma_G_initial = 1
        sigma_WS_eta_initial = 1
        sigma_NE_eta_initial = 1
        lambda_WS_initial = 1
        lambda_NE_initial = 1
        lambda_G_initial = 1
        lambda_WS_eta_initial = 1
        lambda_NE_eta_initial = 1
        alpha_WS_initial = alpha_WS_physics
        alpha_NE_initial = alpha_NE_physics
        alpha_G_initial = alpha_G_physics
        alpha_WS_eta_initial = alpha_WS_eta_physics
        alpha_NE_eta_initial = alpha_NE_eta_physics
    
    # Parameters to Estimate
    Uext_WS = m.FV(value=Uext_WS_initial,lb=0,ub=1.5) # kW / W
    Uext_NE = m.FV(value=Uext_NE_initial,lb=0,ub=1.5) # kW / W
    Uext_G = m.FV(value=Uext_G_initial,lb=0,ub=1.5) # kW / W
    Uext_WS_eta = m.FV(value=Uext_WS_eta_initial,lb=0,ub=1.5) # kW / W
    Uext_NE_eta = m.FV(value=Uext_NE_eta_initial,lb=0,ub=1.5) # kW / W
    Ug_WS = m.FV(value=Ug_WS_initial,lb=0,ub=2) # kW / W
    Ug_NE = m.FV(value=Ug_NE_initial,lb=0,ub=2) # kW / W
    Ug_G = m.FV(value=Ug_G_initial,lb=0,ub=2) # kW / W
    C_WS = m.FV(value=C_WS_initial,lb=0,ub=2) # GJ / K
    C_NE = m.FV(value=C_NE_initial,lb=0,ub=2) # GJ / K
    C_G = m.FV(value=C_G_initial,lb=0,ub=2) # GJ / K
    C_WS_eta = m.FV(value=C_WS_eta_initial,lb=0,ub=2) # GJ / K
    C_NE_eta = m.FV(value=C_NE_eta_initial,lb=0,ub=2) # GJ / K
    U_WS = m.FV(value=U_WS_initial,lb=0,ub=2) # GJ / K
    U_NE = m.FV(value=U_NE_initial,lb=0,ub=2) # GJ / K
    U_rdc = m.FV(value=U_rdc_initial,lb=0,ub=1) # GJ / K
    U_eta = m.FV(value=U_eta_initial,lb=0,ub=1) # GJ / K
    U_rdc_gym = m.FV(value=U_rdc_gym_initial,lb=0,ub=1) # GJ / K
    U_eta_gym = m.FV(value=U_eta_gym_initial,lb=0,ub=1) # GJ / K
    sigma_WS = m.FV(value=sigma_WS_initial,lb=0,ub=10)
    sigma_NE = m.FV(value=sigma_NE_initial,lb=0,ub=10)
    sigma_G = m.FV(value=sigma_G_initial,lb=0,ub=10)
    sigma_WS_eta = m.FV(value=sigma_WS_eta_initial,lb=0,ub=10)
    sigma_NE_eta = m.FV(value=sigma_NE_eta_initial,lb=0,ub=10)
    lambda_WS = m.FV(value=lambda_WS_initial,lb=0,ub=10)
    lambda_NE = m.FV(value=lambda_NE_initial,lb=0,ub=10)
    lambda_G = m.FV(value=lambda_G_initial,lb=0,ub=10)
    lambda_WS_eta = m.FV(value=lambda_WS_eta_initial,lb=0,ub=10)
    lambda_NE_eta = m.FV(value=lambda_NE_eta_initial,lb=0,ub=10)
    alpha_WS = m.FV(value=alpha_WS_initial,lb=0,ub=0.3)
    alpha_NE = m.FV(value=alpha_NE_initial,lb=0,ub=0.3)
    alpha_G = m.FV(value=alpha_G_initial,lb=0,ub=0.3)
    alpha_WS_eta = m.FV(value=alpha_WS_eta_initial,lb=0,ub=0.3)
    alpha_NE_eta = m.FV(value=alpha_NE_eta_initial,lb=0,ub=0.3)

    # STATUS=1 allows solver to adjust parameter
    Uext_WS.STATUS = 1
    Uext_NE.STATUS = 1
    Uext_G.STATUS = 1
    Uext_WS_eta.STATUS = 1
    Uext_NE_eta.STATUS = 1
    Ug_WS.STATUS = 1
    Ug_NE.STATUS = 1
    Ug_G.STATUS = 1
    C_WS.STATUS = 1
    C_NE.STATUS = 1
    C_G.STATUS = 1
    C_WS_eta.STATUS = 1
    C_NE_eta.STATUS = 1
    U_WS.STATUS = 1
    U_NE.STATUS = 1
    U_rdc.STATUS = 1
    U_eta.STATUS = 1
    U_rdc_gym.STATUS = 1
    U_eta_gym.STATUS = 1
    sigma_WS.STATUS = 1
    sigma_NE.STATUS = 1
    sigma_G.STATUS = 1
    sigma_WS_eta.STATUS = 1
    sigma_NE_eta.STATUS = 1
    lambda_WS.STATUS = 1
    lambda_NE.STATUS = 1
    lambda_G.STATUS = 1
    lambda_WS_eta.STATUS = 1
    lambda_NE_eta.STATUS = 1
    alpha_WS.STATUS = 1
    alpha_NE.STATUS = 1
    alpha_G.STATUS = 1
    alpha_WS_eta.STATUS = 1
    alpha_NE_eta.STATUS = 1

    # Measured inputs
    Q_WS = m.MV(value=U_train[:,0])
    Q_NE = m.MV(value=U_train[:,1])
    Q_G = m.MV(value=U_train[:,2])
    Q_WS_eta = m.MV(value=U_train[:,3])
    Q_NE_eta = m.MV(value=U_train[:,4])
    T_ext = m.MV(value=W_train[:,0])
    Tground_WS = m.MV(value=W_train[:,1])
    Tground_NE = m.MV(value=W_train[:,2])
    Tground_G = m.MV(value=W_train[:,3])
    Q_sol_WS = m.MV(value=W_train[:,4])
    Q_sol_NE = m.MV(value=W_train[:,5])
    Q_sol_WS_eta = m.MV(value=W_train[:,6])
    Q_sol_NE_eta = m.MV(value=W_train[:,7])
    Q_int_WS = m.MV(value=W_train[:,8])
    Q_int_NE = m.MV(value=W_train[:,9])
    Q_int_G = m.MV(value=W_train[:,10])
    Q_int_WS_eta = m.MV(value=W_train[:,11])
    Q_int_NE_eta = m.MV(value=W_train[:,12])
    wind_sq = m.MV(value=W_train[:,13])


    # State variables
    T_WS = m.CV(value=X_train[:,0])
    T_NE = m.CV(value=X_train[:,1])
    T_G = m.CV(value=X_train[:,2])
    T_WS_eta = m.CV(value=X_train[:,3])
    T_NE_eta = m.CV(value=X_train[:,4])
    T_WS.FSTATUS = 1    # minimize fstatus * (meas-pred)^2
    T_NE.FSTATUS = 1    # minimize fstatus * (meas-pred)^2
    T_G.FSTATUS = 1    # minimize fstatus * (meas-pred)^2
    T_WS_eta.FSTATUS = 1    # minimize fstatus * (meas-pred)^2
    T_NE_eta.FSTATUS = 1    # minimize fstatus * (meas-pred)^2

    # Semi-fundamental correlations (energy balances)
    m.Equation(C_WS *1e6* T_WS.dt() == (Q_WS + lambda_WS * Q_int_WS + sigma_WS * Q_sol_WS - alpha_WS * wind_sq \
                    + Uext_WS*(T_ext - T_WS) + Ug_WS*(Tground_WS - T_WS) \
                    + U_rdc*(T_NE - T_WS) + U_rdc_gym*(T_G - T_WS) + U_WS*(T_WS_eta - T_WS) ))

    m.Equation(C_NE *1e6* T_NE.dt() == (Q_NE + lambda_NE * Q_int_NE + sigma_NE * Q_sol_NE - alpha_NE * wind_sq \
                    + Uext_NE*(T_ext - T_NE) + Ug_NE*(Tground_NE - T_NE) \
                    + U_rdc*(T_WS - T_NE) + U_NE*(T_NE_eta - T_NE) ))

    m.Equation(C_G *1e6* T_G.dt() == (Q_G + lambda_G * Q_int_G + sigma_G * Q_sol_WS - alpha_G * wind_sq \
                    + Uext_G*(T_ext - T_G) + Ug_G*(Tground_G - T_G) \
                    + U_rdc_gym*(T_WS - T_G) + U_eta_gym*(T_WS_eta - T_G) ))

    m.Equation(C_WS_eta *1e6* T_WS_eta.dt() == (Q_WS_eta + lambda_WS_eta * Q_int_WS_eta + sigma_WS_eta * Q_sol_WS_eta - alpha_WS_eta * wind_sq \
                    + Uext_WS_eta*(T_ext - T_WS_eta) \
                    + U_eta*(T_NE_eta - T_WS_eta) + U_eta_gym*(T_G - T_WS_eta) + U_WS*(T_WS - T_WS_eta) ))

    m.Equation(C_NE_eta *1e6* T_NE_eta.dt() == (Q_NE_eta + lambda_NE_eta * Q_int_NE_eta + sigma_NE_eta * Q_sol_NE_eta - alpha_NE_eta * wind_sq \
                    + Uext_NE_eta*(T_ext - T_NE_eta) \
                    + U_eta*(T_WS_eta - T_NE_eta) + U_NE*(T_NE - T_NE_eta) ))

    # Options
    m.options.IMODE   = 5 # MHE
    m.options.EV_TYPE = 2 # Objective type
    m.options.NODES   = 1 # Collocation nodes
    m.options.SOLVER  = 3 # IPOPT
    
    # Solve
    if (i == i_max and i != 1):
        m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 1
        m.solve(disp=True)
    else:
        m.solve(disp=False)
    
    train_results = {"Uext_WS": Uext_WS.value[0], "Uext_NE": Uext_NE.value[0], "Uext_G": Uext_G.value[0], "Uext_WS_eta": Uext_WS_eta.value[0],
               "Uext_NE_eta": Uext_NE_eta.value[0], "Ug_WS": Ug_WS.value[0], "Ug_NE": Ug_NE.value[0], "Ug_G": Ug_G.value[0], 
               "C_WS": C_WS.value[0], "C_NE": C_NE.value[0], "C_G": C_G.value[0], "C_WS_eta": C_WS_eta.value[0], 
               "C_NE_eta": C_NE_eta.value[0], "U_WS": U_WS.value[0], "U_NE": U_NE.value[0], "U_rdc": U_rdc.value[0], 
               "U_eta": U_eta.value[0], "U_rdc_gym": U_rdc_gym.value[0], "U_eta_gym": U_eta_gym.value[0], 
               "sigma_WS": sigma_WS.value[0], "sigma_NE": sigma_NE.value[0], "sigma_G": sigma_G.value[0], 
               "sigma_WS_eta": sigma_WS_eta.value[0], "sigma_NE_eta": sigma_NE_eta.value[0], "lambda_WS": lambda_WS.value[0], 
               "lambda_NE": lambda_NE.value[0], "lambda_G": lambda_G.value[0], "lambda_WS_eta": lambda_WS_eta.value[0], 
               "lambda_NE_eta": lambda_NE_eta.value[0], "alpha_WS": alpha_WS.value[0], "alpha_NE": alpha_NE.value[0], 
               "alpha_G": alpha_G.value[0], "alpha_WS_eta": alpha_WS_eta.value[0], "alpha_NE_eta": alpha_NE_eta.value[0]}
    
    return train_results
```

It is then applied to a for loop to verify the performance of this model for prediction, doing a new parameter estimation every 24 hours:

```python
#first iteration and initialization
starting_datetime = pd.Timestamp("2015-02-01 00:00", tz="US/Eastern")
n_days_pred = 1
i = 1
i_max = 1
n_timesteps = int(n_days_pred*24*3600 / timestep)
finishing_datetime = starting_datetime + timedelta(hours = (24*n_days_pred))
train_results = train (starting_datetime,finishing_datetime,i,i_max)
finishing_datetime = starting_datetime + timedelta(hours = (24*n_days_pred*2))
X_pred = prediction (train_results, starting_datetime,finishing_datetime)
#the rest of the iterations
training_time = []
params=[]
i_max = 13
for i in range (2,i_max+1):
    finishing_datetime = starting_datetime + timedelta(hours = (24*n_days_pred*i))
    start_train = time.time()
    train_results = train (starting_datetime,finishing_datetime,i,i_max)
    print(train_results)
    end_train = time.time()
    training_time.append(end_train - start_train)
    print(i)
    print(training_time)
    params.append(train_results)
    starting_datetime_pred = finishing_datetime
    finishing_datetime_pred = finishing_datetime + timedelta(hours = (24*n_days_pred*1))
    X_pred_new = prediction (train_results, starting_datetime_pred,finishing_datetime_pred)
    X_pred = np.concatenate((X_pred,X_pred_new[-n_timesteps:]))
```

The prediction function is just the same model that uses the trained parameters to make predictions for the temperatures of the 5 building zones (IMODE 4).
Almost all the time is spent computing the parameter estimation.
The training computation time at every iteration is:
[  17.77,   34.25,   61.95,   97.31,  152.96,  215.53,  319.42,
463.88,  548.74,  691.37,  946.15, 1144.1 ]
Last iteration takes around 19 minutes and it uses a 2 weeks dataset. The report of this last iteration, with the computation times included (DIAGLEVEL=1), is the following (i had to cut some parts because of characters limit):

```
 Called files( 35 )
 READ info FILE FOR VARIABLE DEFINITION: gk_model116.info
 initialization step:  0
 Parsing model file gk_model116.apm
 Read model file (sec): 0.013000000000000012
 Initialize constants (sec): 0.
 Determine model size (sec): 0.006000000000000005
 Allocate memory (sec): 0.
 Parse and store model (sec): 0.0030000000000000027
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  0
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  58
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  0
   Equations    :  5
   Residuals    :  5
 
 Error checking (sec): 0.0010000000000000009
 Compile equations (sec): 0.002999999999999975
 Check for uninitialized intermediates (sec): 0.
 ------------------------------------------------------
 Total Parse Time (sec): 0.027000000000000007
 initialization step:  1
 initialization step:  2
 initialization step:  3
 Called files( 8 )
 Files(8): File Read ss.t0 F
 files: ss.t0 does not exist
 Called files( 31 )
 READ info FILE FOR PROBLEM DEFINITION: gk_model116.info
 initialization step:  4
 Called files( 31 )
 READ info FILE FOR PROBLEM DEFINITION: gk_model116.info
 WARNING: restart file not found - est.t0
 Called files( 51 )
 Read DBS File defaults.dbs
 files: defaults.dbs does not exist
 Called files( 51 )
 Read DBS File gk_model116.dbs
 files: gk_model116.dbs does not exist
 Called files( 51 )
 Read DBS File measurements.dbs
 Called files( 51 )
 Read DBS File overrides.dbs
 files: overrides.dbs does not exist
 Number of state variables:    179746
 Number of total equations: -  179712
 Number of slack variables: -  0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    34

This is Ipopt version 3.10.2, running with linear solver mumps.

Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:   501691
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:   183456

Total number of variables............................:   179746
                     variables with only lower bounds:        0
                variables with lower and upper bounds:       34
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:   179712
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0

Number of Iterations....: 48

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:  1.4797975081572714e+005   1.4797975081572714e+005
Dual infeasibility......:  1.4113310324500653e-009   1.4113310324500653e-009
Constraint violation....:  1.6653345369377348e-015   4.2632564145606011e-014
Complementarity.........:  1.0942671862849926e-008   1.0942671862849926e-008
Overall NLP error.......:  7.3565689235462651e-010   1.0942671862849926e-008


Number of objective function evaluations             = 56
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 49
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 56
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 49
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 48
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =     65.561
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =     80.763

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

 The solution was found.

 The final value of the objective function is  147979.75081572714
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :  156.5746999999999 sec
 Objective      :  147979.75081572714
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
 Called files( 2 )
 Called files( 65 )
 Called files( 66 )
 Called files( 83 )
 Called files( 81 )
 Called files( 52 )
 WRITE dbs FILE
 Called files( 56 )
 WRITE json FILE
Timer #     1    1141.17/       1 =    1141.17 Total system time
Timer #     2     156.57/       1 =     156.57 Total solve time
Timer #     3      11.16/      56 =       0.20 Objective Calc: apm_p
Timer #     4      11.36/      50 =       0.23 Objective Grad: apm_g
Timer #     5       9.31/      56 =       0.17 Constraint Calc: apm_c
Timer #     6       0.00/       1 =       0.00 Sparsity: apm_s
Timer #     7       7.96/      50 =       0.16 1st Deriv #1: apm_a1
Timer #     8       0.00/       0 =       0.00 1st Deriv #2: apm_a2
Timer #     9       0.91/    7488 =       0.00 Custom Init: apm_custom_init
Timer #    10       0.19/    7488 =       0.00 Mode: apm_node_res::case 0
Timer #    11       0.12/   22464 =       0.00 Mode: apm_node_res::case 1
Timer #    12       0.46/    7488 =       0.00 Mode: apm_node_res::case 2
Timer #    13       0.06/   14976 =       0.00 Mode: apm_node_res::case 3
Timer #    14       4.80/  883584 =       0.00 Mode: apm_node_res::case 4
Timer #    15      11.88/  748800 =       0.00 Mode: apm_node_res::case 5
Timer #    16      10.17/  366912 =       0.00 Mode: apm_node_res::case 6
Timer #    17       2.34/      50 =       0.05 Base 1st Deriv: apm_jacobian
Timer #    18       0.00/       0 =       0.00 Base 1st Deriv: apm_condensed_jacobian
Timer #    19       0.06/       1 =       0.06 Non-zeros: apm_nnz
Timer #    20       0.00/       0 =       0.00 Count: Division by zero
Timer #    21       0.00/       0 =       0.00 Count: Argument of LOG10 negative
Timer #    22       0.00/       0 =       0.00 Count: Argument of LOG negative
Timer #    23       0.00/       0 =       0.00 Count: Argument of SQRT negative
Timer #    24       0.00/       0 =       0.00 Count: Argument of ASIN illegal
Timer #    25       0.00/       0 =       0.00 Count: Argument of ACOS illegal
Timer #    26       0.05/       1 =       0.05 Extract sparsity: apm_sparsity
Timer #    27       0.41/      17 =       0.02 Variable ordering: apm_var_order
Timer #    28       0.00/       0 =       0.00 Condensed sparsity
Timer #    29       9.32/       1 =       9.32 Hessian Non-zeros
Timer #    30       0.54/       4 =       0.14 Differentials
Timer #    31       7.63/      48 =       0.16 Hessian Calculation
Timer #    32       1.89/      49 =       0.04 Extract Hessian
Timer #    33       0.19/       1 =       0.19 Base 1st Deriv: apm_jac_order
Timer #    34       0.24/       1 =       0.24 Solver Setup
Timer #    35      66.11/       1 =      66.11 Solver Solution
Timer #    36       2.30/      68 =       0.03 Number of Variables
Timer #    37       0.14/       5 =       0.03 Number of Equations
Timer #    38       1.42/      19 =       0.07 File Read/Write
Timer #    39       0.01/       1 =       0.01 Dynamic Init A
Timer #    40     138.16/       1 =     138.16 Dynamic Init B
Timer #    41     833.15/       1 =     833.15 Dynamic Init C
Timer #    42       0.01/       1 =       0.01 Init: Read APM File
Timer #    43       0.00/       1 =       0.00 Init: Parse Constants
Timer #    44       0.01/       1 =       0.01 Init: Model Sizing
Timer #    45       0.00/       1 =       0.00 Init: Allocate Memory
Timer #    46       0.00/       1 =       0.00 Init: Parse Model
Timer #    47       0.00/       1 =       0.00 Init: Check for Duplicates
Timer #    48       0.00/       1 =       0.00 Init: Compile Equations
Timer #    49       0.00/       1 =       0.00 Init: Check Uninitialized
Timer #    50       0.00/    7590 =       0.00 Evaluate Expression Once
Timer #    51       0.00/       0 =       0.00 Sensitivity Analysis: LU Factorization
Timer #    52       0.00/       0 =       0.00 Sensitivity Analysis: Gauss Elimination
Timer #    53       0.00/       0 =       0.00 Sensitivity Analysis: Total Time
```

"Dynamic Init. C" takes 833 seconds on 1141. So that is definitely my bottleneck.

How I can improve it?
I already tried to change IMODE or SOLVER but without success.
I'll have to compute also an optimization (that will use also this model) for my MPC so it's quite important for me to reduce computation times.

Thanks to everyone that will answer to this post. If more data is needed to reproduce the code I could provide the rest of the training data (I would have to provide lot of code and some txt files)

Comment: This is a very large model.  Are you surprised that it takes 20 minutes?

Comment: @TimRoberts It is quite large but I was suprised the compiling of the model took over 70% of the time and the solver took few time. So I was wondering if I was doing something wrong. After Prof. Hedengren suggestion of using `m.Param` instead of `m.MV` computation time reduced by a factor of 7 on the last training iteration with a dataset of 2 weeks. So it now takes 168 seconds instead of 20 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impressive application! Here is a summary of the model size for the nonlinear differential and algebraic equations once they are fully discretized:

```
 Number of state variables:    179746
 Number of total equations: -  179712
 Number of slack variables: -  0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    34
```

IPOPT requires `156.57` sec to solve while the model compilation requires `984.60` sec. The model building phases `A`, `B`, and `C` are the translation of the model into byte-code with automatic differentiation. The time grows with a longer time horizon because more instances of the model collocation equations are added with the longer horizon.

Without this byte-code compile, the model evaluation speed would be much slower if evaluated in Python. Here is a summary of how long the model evaluations took once they were compiled:

```
Timer # 14  4.80 sec for  883584 times (eqn Residuals)
Timer # 15 11.88 sec for  748800 times (sparse Jacobian)
Timer # 16 10.17 sec for  366912 times (sparse Hessian)
```

There is a [feature request in GitHub](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/153) to store the compiled model so that it only needs to be built once. There is some functionality to keep the compiled model with the [REPLAY option](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmReplay), but it isn't ready for Gekko MHE yet.

Here are a few recommendations to increase the speed with the current version of Gekko:

- Increase the sparsity of the time horizon to 10-60 mins timesteps when solved over a week
- Include a forgetting factor to approximate the effect past data and a longer horizon. The balancing parameters are `WMEAS` (weight on measurements) and `WMODEL` (weight on prior model prediction). A higher `WMODEL` allows a shorter time horizon with similar results as you run the MHE over more data.
- Calculate the new parameters every hour and control the time shift of the data and model initial conditions with `m.options.TIME_SHIFT`. Use `12` for a 1 hour time shift with 5 min sampled data.
- Change `m.MV()` to `m.Param()` because the additional `MV` equations are not needed for this application where it is only input data.

Please post follow-up comments based on anything that helps or if you still need additional suggestions.

Comment: Thank you very much Professor for the quick answer and for all your work behind the GEKKO library, which really impressed me. I have tried the solutions you proposed (except, for now, increasing the timestep), and what made much difference is to change the `m.MV` to `m.Param`. Now the last iteration takes 168 s (of which 23 of IPOPT) against the 1141 of before!! Instead adding `TIME_SHIFT = 12` brings to a slight slowdown (175 s) and adding `T.WMODEL = 4.0` for the 5 states brings it to 186. Now it's quite fast! I will consider increasing the timestamp if I need to further increase the speed.

Comment: I was now trying to add a 6th state that is the temperature inside of the external wall of the building which means to have a state that has no measurement but it must be estimated by the model. I first tried to use an `MV` with `STATUS = 1` but then it cannot have the differential `.dt()` on it. So I switched to `CV` with FSTATUS=0 and STATUS = 1 but I am either having weird results or infinite calculation time. What is the proper way to define that state?

Comment: For an estimation problem, define the measured values as `m.CV()` and set `m.options.IMODE=5` with `FSTATUS=1` and `STATUS=0`. Please create a new question for more specific help.